# Call by Reference or by Value?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

I have just begun using C++, with a base in C. Having learned about Call by reference, I need to know,if in the following function I found online:

```
int insertSorted(int arr[], int n, int key, int capacity)
{
    if (n >= capacity)
        return n;

    arr[n] = key;
    return (n+1);
}
```

,which is used for insertion in an unsorted array, will the array in the main function get affected/changed? Since the `arr[]` argument in the function is not a reference variable, so how do any changes in this called function, reflect in the calling function? Is this correct code, if at all? I am basing my question upon the fact that call by value, creates copy variables and changes them, while call by reference changes the actual variables themselves. I'm sorry if this question is a bit silly. 
Any help in clearing up this concept would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: arrays are references regardless of passing the ampersand (&) or not.

Comment: "arrays are references" - no, they are not.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI - No they aren't.  They decay to pointers, and pointers are passed by value.

Comment: There is no need to put ampersand, the changes will be shown after func. call.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so if they're passed by value, then how is the array in the main(calling) function getting changed? Will this code work?

Comment: The code will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, to understand this you also need to understand pointers.  Pointers are a bit like references, but also fundamentally different :(

Comment: Somewhat related: In C++ you shouldn't be using raw arrays, instead use `std::vector` or `std::array`

Comment: I know a bit about pointers too, could you explain it in brief?

Comment: @AngadSingh - Your code is equivalent to `int insertSorted(int *arr, int n, int key, int capacity)`.  So you're actually passing a pointer, by value.  So changes to the pointer itself (e.g. `arr = NULL`) will not be reflected in the caller.  However, changes to the thing the pointer points at **will** be reflected.

Comment: Your function doesn't insert sorted. It simply appends.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is effectively a pointer to the array. Thus, in your case it acts like a reference and the function changes the array `arr` points to.

If you want to do it more the C++ way you should use a `std::vector<int>` instead of a `int[]` for your array. `std::vector` has all features of a C-style array but takes care of memory management and the actual number of elements.

In case of a `std::vector` you really have to pass a reference (`std::vector &`), otherwise the function will receive a copy of the entire array.

Comment: "arr is effectively a pointer to the array" `arr` is actually a pointer to an `int`. A pointer to an array is something different.

Comment: That's why I wrote "effectively" to point out it is not _strictly_ a pointer to an array.